# How does the GSM stack uses the SIM card on android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, gsm

I would like to know how the SIM card is used in the Android stack. I am not extremely familiar with the rest of the operating system or the network protocols, therefore I would be glad to have an explanation as detailed as possible. Don't hesitate to give some links to the kernel code, documentation, RFCs and interface specification from telecommunication networks (I have skimmed over  ETSI TS 131 102 and TS 121 111).

If applicable, I am more interested in the standards used in Europe (especially the network authentication part).

As for the reason why I need this information; my android smartphone's SIM card reader is broken, and I do not see a reason why I couldn't use an external one. The ideal solution would be to copy the credentials stored in the SIM card and use them with some software on the Android side, but I would expect them to contain (at least for recent ones) strong, not externally readable cryptographic secrets. Another solution would be to build an external SIM card reader linked to the phone, to perform the authentication on the network (only this part, if possible; but it could also be necessary to perform this when roaming from cell to cell, for example).

Ideally, I would use an external USB card reader, but I am not sure it is possible, at least by default.

This question may sound like it doesn't belong to SO, but I believe it *is* a programming question, since the answer will determine where the solution will plug in.

Comment: 3G modem usually has a separate CPU with closed source software.

Answer (score 1):

there is no "gsm stack" nor in android nor in linux. android uses the tty based (AT commands) access to the GSM modem which is external (to the kernel) device. the only way is to fix/replace the SIM connector or use the gsm usb dongle. there are exist the GSM modems with virtual "software" SIM's but I'd not heard any of such used with android.

Comment: I already replaced the connector without success. I will get a new phone, but this is a good opportunity to learn more about GSM, SIM cards and Android. I would be surprised if the phone functionality was not split into a frontend (ui/settings/dialer) - backend (interface to low level hardware) architecture, like bluez, for example. Enabling a new card adapter would then just require interfacing with the backend, at the right place. This would also have the benefit of making multi-SIM adapters easier to make. You also seem to imply that USB GSM dongles work, do you have more information?

Comment: Well, Android supports USB GSM dongles since 2.3 I think. Every cheap Android car audio do this just out of the box.